# code highlighting apex (Firefox 31)

Tags: oracle, firefox, oracle-apex, highlighting

The Oracle Application Express code editor is just plain back text on white background. No Code highlighting. Also I can't press "tab" without the textfield loosing focus.

I am using firefox 31 (can't upgrade, rescricted by Admin at work here) Also I can't install plugins. I know you can change css on specific sites using a special folder in firefox ("chrome"-folder / userContent.css). I already used this to change die default size of the textfield, because it was frickin small everytime I opened the edit page.

So do you know any framework or script I can use in Apex ? (I could copy that shit to jsfiddle.net every time but that sucks

(I also found the scratchpad in Firefox, which can run js and jquery. Does that help ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]
since you can't use

```
    <script src = "">
```

etc. in plain js, I had to use loadScript. For css files it was even more complicated, but I got it all working.

This is my code, I run it in scratchpad (firefox). It uses ACE to change a div to an editor with highlighting. When clicking apply I revert the editor-changes in the DOM but keep the text/code.

```
    // Load Ace js
    loadScript("http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.01/ace.js", function(){
        //initialization code
    });
    // Load Ace css
    var cssId = 'myCss';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
    if (!document.getElementById(cssId)){
        var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var link  = document.createElement('link');
        link.id   = cssId;
        link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.href = 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css';
        link.media = 'all';
        head.appendChild(link);
    }
    // change textarea to div
    var editorRegion = document.getElementById('F4000_P4651_PLUG_SOURCE_fieldset');
    editorRegion.innerHTML = editorRegion.innerHTML.replace("textarea","div");

    // run ACE
    highlight();


    // Modify the apply Button in Apex to first revert ACE-Editor to normal, then do the usual apply.
    var applyChanges = document.getElementById('B3456326662');
    applyChanges.setAttribute("onclick","modifiedApply()");
    function modifiedApply(){
      close();
      setTimeout(normalApply, 500);
    }
    function normalApply(){
      javascript:apex.submit('Apply_Changes');
    }

    // Revert ACE-Changes, but keep changed text/code.
    function close(){
        var value = editor.getValue();
        editor.destroy();
        var oldDiv = editor.container;
        var newDiv = oldDiv.cloneNode(false);
        newDiv.textContent = value;
        oldDiv.parentNode.replaceChild(newDiv, oldDiv);
        newDiv.outerHTML = newDiv.outerHTML.replace("div","textarea");
        var old_new_old = document.getElementById('F4000_P4651_PLUG_SOURCE');
        old_new_old.textContent = old_new_old.textContent.substring(0, old_new_old.textContent.length - 6);
    }
    var editor;
    function highlight() {
      editor = ace.edit("F4000_P4651_PLUG_SOURCE");
      editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
      editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
      editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
      document.getElementsByClassName('ace_print-margin')[0].setAttribute("style","left:1000px");
    }


    function loadScript(url, callback){
        var script = document.createElement("script")
        script.type = "text/javascript";

        if (script.readyState){  //IE
            script.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                        script.readyState == "complete"){
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    callback();
                }
            };
        } else {  //Others
            script.onload = function(){
                callback();
            };
        }
        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }
```